# Using BootStrap class to load data into database, but only part of data is loaded

Tags: grails

I'm loading data into my model from BootStrap.groovy but I can't figure out why only the first set of 4(ListItPlan) are the only ones getting loaded to the database(hql).  When I look at the tables using dbconsole, the other two tables are empty (Plan,Cred).  Does it have something to do with the order in which the data is loaded or maybe constraints (which I only have on the ListItPlan model)?

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        new ListItPlan(m_id: "248656", plan_id: "12345XX9876543").save()
        new ListItPlan(m_id: "209459", plan_id: "12345XX9876543").save()
        new ListItPlan(m_id: "248656", plan_id: "56748XXX123933").save()
        new ListItPlan(m_id: "209459", plan_id: "56748XXX123933").save()

        new Plan(plan_id: "12345XX9876543", p_id_type: "PLAN-ID").save()
        new Plan(plan_id: "56748XXX123933", p_id_type: "PLAN-ID").save()

        new Cred(m_id: "248656", d_name: "Lorem Ipsum").save()
        new Cred(m_id: "209459", d_name: "Ipsum").save()
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

fyi: I don't see any errors in the console.

So, now I'm having trouble with the pk constraint. After doing some reading, I know the belongsTo and hasMany is the culprit, but I cannot seem to get the order correct when adding the data.  Do I create the Cred first and then put it in the ListItPlan? Like this...

```
def d1 = new Cred(m_id: "248656", d_name: "Lorem Ipsum").save(failOnError:     true)
def ldp1 = new ListItPlan(Cred : d1, plan_id: "12345XX9876543").save(failOnError: true)
```

Here's my model...
    …
    class ListItPlan {
        String m_id
        String plan_id

```
    String toString() {
        "${plan_id}"
    }
    static hasMany = [creds : Cred, plans : Plan]

    static constraints = {
        m_id()
        plan_id()
    }
}
…
class Cred {
    String m_id
    String g_name
    static belongsTo = [owner : ListItPlan]
    static hasMany = [plans : Plan]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
…
class Plan {
    String plan_id
    String plan_id_type
    static belongsTo = [listItPlan : ListItPlan, cred: Cred]

    static constraints = {  
    }
}
```

Comment: Change all your `.save()` to `.save(failOnError: true)` and see if you find any errors.

Comment: Ahhh...that helped.  I see now that there's a primary key constraint.

Comment: Since hibernate manages when the data is stored in the database, it may not necessarily make all the data persistent. You can force the hibernate to immediately commit the data to the database using .save(flush: true)